# If an Apache Solr field isn't defined in schema.xml, is it not searhcable by default?

Tags: solr

I have a Solr field that isn't defined in my schema.xml, but is part of my Solr documents.  I'm having issues querying the content of the field.  Is this because it's not searchable by default or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that you are not creating a field dynamically and want to search on a field: you should define it as indexed at your schema. i.e.:

```
<field name="content" type="text_tr" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
```